# Unable to build project after updating to Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5, jailbreak

I have just updated my Xcode to 5.1.1 and I am unable to build my project. Xcode gives this error

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-fno_objc_arc' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Did you type that option in manually?  I ask as it should be `-fno-objc-arc`.

Answer (score 1):

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-fno_objc_arc'
```

The flag which you set for disable arc in file  is wrong it should be `-fno-objc-arc`
For more reference refer [How to disable arc flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)